# How to extract List items from website into DataFrame? (Clear example given)

Tags: python, selenium

I feel at the outset I should mention that this is a purely personal project.

I am looking to scrape car data from a well known car website. Their website for each car "product card" is structured as follows:

```
<section class="product-card-details">
    <h3 class="product-card-details__title">
Mercedes-Benz A-Class
    </h3>

    <p class="product-card-details__subtitle">
1.3 A 200 AMG LINE 5d 161 BHP | 14-DAYS MONEY BACK GUARANTEE*
    </p>

        <p class="product-card-details__attention-grabber">
***FREE 3 MONTHS WARRANTY***
        </p>

    <ul class="listing-key-specs">

            <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">2018 (68 reg)</li>
        
            <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">Hatchback</li>
        
            <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">39,009 miles</li>
        
            <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">1.3L</li>
        
            <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">161BHP</li>
        
            <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">Automatic</li>
        
            <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">Petrol</li>
        
            <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">1 owner</li>
        
            <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">ULEZ</li>
        

    </ul>
</section>
```

I am able to extract the title and the subtitle in a loop quite easily as follows:

```
#Find Elements by Class Name. Create array of all cards
car_list = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "product-card-details")

titles = []
subtitles = []

for car in car_list:
    title = car.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "product-card-details__title").text
    subtitle = car.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "product-card-details__subtitle").text
```

However, i am having real difficulty accessing the list elements, I call them the "specs" for each vehicle. I have attempted the following:

```
specs = car.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//li[contains(@class, 'atc-type-picanto--medium')]")
for spec in specs:
    print(spec.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

However, this outputs **all** specs for **all** cars on each loop. (Why?)

I have also tried the following:

```
specs = car.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "listing-key-specs").get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(specs)
```

Which outputs:

```
        <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">2018 (68 reg)</li>
    
        <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">Hatchback</li>
    
        <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">39,009 miles</li>
    
        <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">1.3L</li>
    
        <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">161BHP</li>
    
        <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">Automatic</li>
    
        <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">Petrol</li>
    
        <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">1 owner</li>
    
        <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">ULEZ</li>
```

And i cannot seem to extract each element, it only extracts as a block.

Ideally i'd like to create a list of lists:

```
all_specs = [[car1spec1, car1spec2, ...], [car2spec1, car2spec2, ...]]
```

And so on. Any help would be much appreciated as I have spent a few days trying to figure this out.

Comment: Have you tried [Beautiful Soup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#quick-start) a lib dedicated to web scraping ?

Comment: Beautifulsoup requests are denied to the website. I am close with my code above, I just need assistance in the last part.

Comment: Too bad. I don't have time to dig into your use case. Hope you'll have success. With beautifulsoup had you tried to spoof the User-Agent ?

Answer (score 1):

I created an html page with the code you pasted:

```
<html>
<body>
<section class="product-card-details">
    <h3 class="product-card-details__title">
Mercedes-Benz A-Class
    </h3>

    <p class="product-card-details__subtitle">
1.3 A 200 AMG LINE 5d 161 BHP | 14-DAYS MONEY BACK GUARANTEE*
    </p>

        <p class="product-card-details__attention-grabber">
***FREE 3 MONTHS WARRANTY***
        </p>

    <ul class="listing-key-specs">

            <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">2018 (68 reg)</li>

            <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">Hatchback</li>

            <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">39,009 miles</li>

            <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">1.3L</li>

            <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">161BHP</li>

            <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">Automatic</li>

            <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">Petrol</li>

            <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">1 owner</li>

            <li class="atc-type-picanto--medium">ULEZ</li>


    </ul>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I took your code and ran it. It worked well. This is the code I used:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('file:///home/eugene/cars_example.html')
car_list = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "product-card-details")

titles = []
subtitles = []

for car in car_list:
    title = car.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "product-card-details__title").text
    subtitle = car.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "product-card-details__subtitle").text
    specs = car.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "li")
    specs_entries = []
    for spec in specs:
        entry = spec.get_attribute('innerHTML')
        specs_entries.append(entry)
driver.quit()
print(specs_entries)
```

and this is the result:

```
2018 (68 reg)
Hatchback
39,009 miles
1.3L
161BHP
Automatic
Petrol
1 owner
ULEZ
```

So, looks like everything works as expected. I'm not answering with the solution of the problem. But maybe you'll find any mistake in your code using my example.

Comment: Really appreciate the response Eugeny. I am still unsure why find element by "TAG_NAME" works in this instance, but my attempt (By.XPATH,"//li[contains(@class, 'atc-type-picanto--medium')]") didn't?

Comment: It worked both with  `(By.XPATH,"//li[contains(@class, 'atc-type-picanto--medium')]") ` and `by "TAG_NAME" `, I've just changed it for simplicity.

Comment: You actually seemed to have gotten rid of the initialisation of the list outside of the loop. Previously I had specs = [] set up outside the loop. Could this have been why?

Comment: I've tried this now and it changed nothing. You mean put the line `specs = []` before `for car in car_list:`, right? And everything else stays the same?

Comment: Hi Eugeny. I've found that when i don't do print() and instead i do something like:     for spec in specs:
        entry = spec.get_attribute('innerHTML')
        specs.append(entry) I get an error that 'str type doesn't have attribute innerHTML'. I cannot figure out why that is the case? All i want to do is add the results to a list so that I can put them into a dataframe along with all the other data points of each vehicle.

Comment: You are using the same variable `specs`. And as a result you are rewriting its content. First you do `specs = car.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "li")` and it contains elements and then you do `specs.append(entry)` and this adds strings to the end of the list of elements, so you are getting the error. I've updated my answer with the correct code with collecting the entries to a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
specs = car.find_elements(By.XPATH,".//li[contains(@class, 'atc-type-picanto--medium')]")
```

If you wanted to know what's wrong it's the xpath from an element you need to use a . prior to it. It's specifically the usage of xpath and not the other types here.

Comment: I cannot get this to work with the ".". Are you suggesting that i was getting duplicated results because it wasn't referring to the correct relative path?

Comment: Yes that was what I was referring to.